# React native Enzyme Mount Native elements "unrecognized in this browser"

Tags: react-native, enzyme

React Native app with Expo.
Installed Jest and Enzyme

Want to run Enzyme `Mount` on the component so I can test state updates.

I have this simple test

```
describe("State checking", () => {
    test("Make sure that State gets added from Route params", () => {
        const component = mount(<Categories/>);
        const instance = component.instance();
        console.log(instance);
    })
})
```

When running this, I get this error from the test:

```
Warning: <View /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
Warning: The tag <View> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

What is going on here? Does it not recognize that I am using React Native?

I have researched this issue but get nothing useful.

Thank you for your time.